# Problems using Neo4j ETL CLI tool to Load from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to use the following tool to load data from a MySQL (MariaDB, technically) database into Neo4j (both running on same Centos 7 Linux Machine).

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl

I've got it downloaded and I've got a root user on the MySQL database with privileges granted across all databases/schemas.

Because I'm using MySQL, I shouldn't need to manually load and configure a JDBC (according to the link above, it is built-in to the latest version of the Neo4j-ETL software).

I'm executing the following command to try and run the executable (as root user):

```
./neo4j-etl export --rdbms:url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 --rdbms:user root --rdbms:password password --destination /var/lib/neo4j/data/new_databases/graph.db --import-tool /usr/bin/ --csv-directory /var/lib/neo4j/import --debug
```

This command results in the following messages:

```
INFO: Skipping reading import options from file because file [] doesn't exist.
FINE: Connecting to database...
SEVERE: Could not connect to the host database. Please check your credentials
java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure                                                                                                            either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want                                                                                                            to utilize time zone support.
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
      at org.neo4j.etl.sql.DatabaseClient.<init>(DatabaseClient.java:65)
      at org.neo4j.etl.cli.rdbms.ImportFromRdbmsCli.run(ImportFromRdbmsCli.java:134)
      at org.neo4j.etl.util.CliRunner.run(CliRunner.java:42)
      at org.neo4j.etl.util.CliRunner.run(CliRunner.java:35)
      at org.neo4j.etl.NeoIntegrationCli.main(NeoIntegrationCli.java:43)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or repres                                                                                                           ents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property)                                                                                                            to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
      at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2234)
      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2258)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:966)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
      ... 10 more

java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure                                                                                                            either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want                                                                                                            to utilize time zone support.
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
      at org.neo4j.etl.sql.DatabaseClient.<init>(DatabaseClient.java:65)
      at org.neo4j.etl.cli.rdbms.ImportFromRdbmsCli.run(ImportFromRdbmsCli.java:134)
      at org.neo4j.etl.util.CliRunner.run(CliRunner.java:42)
      at org.neo4j.etl.util.CliRunner.run(CliRunner.java:35)
      at org.neo4j.etl.NeoIntegrationCli.main(NeoIntegrationCli.java:43)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'EDT' is unrecognized or repres                                                                                                           ents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property)                                                                                                            to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
      at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
      at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2234)
      at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2258)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:966)
      at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
      ... 10 more
It seems 'java' command is not available.
Please check your JAVA_HOME environment variable.
Also check if you have a valid Java 8 environment
```

When I run 'java -version', I get the following, which leads me to believe that my java is okay, despite the error messages:

```
[root@NEO42 bin]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Both the Neo4j database and the MySQL database live on the server which I'm executing from (localhost). I've tried creating another user in MySQL (which I also granted all privileges for) but when executing the command, I receive the same errors.

Does anyone have any ideas on what my problem could be here? Any tips, suggestions or pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out where I went wrong. I was specifying the wrong path for the import tool and in the connection URL, I needed to specify the database requested for extraction and import and also needed to specify timezone. Look at the command below for the changes:

```
./neo4j-etl export --rdbms:url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=EST --rdbms:user root --rdbms:password password --destination /var/lib/neo4j/data/new_databases/graph.db --import-tool /usr/share/neo4j/bin/ --csv-directory /var/lib/neo4j/import --debug
```

Unfortunately, while this mainly answers my question here, there another issue and it seems like it might be a version incompatibility issue, specifically the error I'm seeing is below:

```
Input error: Missing argument 'into'
Caused by:Missing argument 'into'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing argument 'into'
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.Converters.lambda$mandatory$0(Converters.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.helpers.Args.interpretOption(Args.java:542)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:408)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:360)
', DurationMillis: 322 }]
```

I'm going to create another question for this issue to focus the area of questioning on my problem.